# Access array.length to render number from MongoDB database in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following Mongo Schema which has an array of objects inside of 'balance':

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  balance: [{
    balanceDate: Date,
    newBalance: Number
  }],
});
```

An example console.log of said Schema would then be like this:

```
balance: Array [
    {
      id: "20304929403048fd636",
      balanceDate: "2020-11-23T10:57:58.845Z",
      newBalance: 300
    },
    {
      id:"20fhdjfjwjh39g9395",
      balanceDate: "2020-11-23T11:54.58.845Z",
      newBalance: 200
    } ]
```

I then have an Axios call which sets an array state like follows:

```
  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get("/api/fetch/fetchDebtCards")
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        debts: response.data
      })
      console.log(this.state.debts)
    })

  }
```

Finally, I have the following function which I'm attempting to use to render the results on my web page.

```
const fetchDebts = this.state.debts.map (debt => {

      return (

       <IndividualDebtCard key={debt._id}
        balance={debt.balance[debt.balance.length - 1][2]}
       />

            )
        })
```

This maps through my database, and is attempting to pull the **last balance entry** to render as props on my web page.

From this last balance entry, I then want to pull **the newBalance figure to render in my webpage**. So in this example, balance would equal 200.

However, the array.length isn't working. I can't seem to access the last newBalance in my array.

I have simplified my call as it also pulls other entry details, but for simplicity's sake I have removed them. The rest of the call works fine! So it's not a problem with anything else, just getting the last value in the array.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I can add more details if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is happening because you are using array of objects and trying to get the second index from balance object. For example **balance[1][2]** is undefined because you can't access objects by index. You can only access objects by key. You can try using **balance[1].newBalance** if that solves it.

```
const fetchDebts = this.state.debts.map (debt => {

  return (
    <IndividualDebtCard key={debt._id}
      balance={debt.balance[debt.balance.length - 1].newBalance}
    />
  )
})
```